# SQL query for joining two columns into one

Tags: sql, union, concatenation

I have a table of matches and scores, which looks something like this

```
match_id | player1 | player2 | player1_score | player2_score |
---------|---------|---------|---------------|---------------|
       1 |       1 |       2 |            30 |            50 |
       2 |       3 |       1 |            35 |            10 |
       3 |       1 |       4 |            40 |            20 |
       4 |       2 |       3 |            20 |            25 |
       5 |       4 |       2 |            65 |            15 |
       6 |       3 |       4 |            10 |            20 |
```

and I want to make a query with the scores in a single column

```
match_id | player | opponent | score |
---------|--------|----------|-------|
       1 |      1 |        2 |    30 |
       2 |      3 |        1 |    35 |
       3 |      1 |        4 |    40 |
       4 |      2 |        3 |    20 |
       5 |      4 |        2 |    65 |
       6 |      3 |        4 |    10 |
       1 |      2 |        1 |    50 |
       2 |      1 |        3 |    10 |
       3 |      4 |        1 |    20 |
       4 |      3 |        2 |    25 |
       5 |      2 |        4 |    15 |
       6 |      4 |        3 |    20 |
```

This would be equivalent to concatenating some columns in the table with others:

```
match_id |  player | opponent |         score |
---------|---------|----------|---------------|
match_id | player1 |  player2 | player1_score |
match_id | player2 |  player1 | player2_score |
```

but I'm not not sure what the appropriate operation would be. `join` is the only operation I know that combines tables, but it seems like the wrong tool here.

Either `CONCAT` or `UNION` seems reasonable, but which would be preferable here? And what would the query be?

Comment: Which DBMS (MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, ...) are you using?

Comment: You are looking for `UNION ALL` and column aliases. Is it necessary to get the results in the order you are showning? For this is a tad more complicated than the mere union all query.

Comment: RDBMS is relevant as there may be ways to do this without scanning the table twice depending on which one you are using

Comment: @ThorstenKettner The order isn't important.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

seems you need  an union

```
    select match_id, player1, player2 opponent, player1_score score
    from my_table 
    union all 
    select match_id, player1, player2 , player2_score 
    from my_table
```